# How to pass multiple selected items from a listbox to a select parameter in a ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, listbox, reportviewer, objectdatasource

I have a listbox where a user can select multiple items from it, but I need to pass these multiple selected items to a select parameter in an object data source, which will then fire off a query for a reportviewer report.

Now, I can easily get it to work for one selected item, but how do I get it work for more than one?

Thanks

Comment: so how is the sql for this query currentky set?

Comment: Dynamic SQL with an in clause that allows for multiple values. This works as I have tested it in Sql Management Studio

Comment: Sorry for wasting people's time, but I have solved it with stringbuilder class.

Comment: Well post the answer then. Someone might get something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but might help others.
ListItemCollection isn't serializable so you can't use Items property as ControlParameter.

After reading some solutions that not satisfied me, I extended ListBox class as:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ListBoxExtended runat=server></{0}:ListBoxExtended>")]
public class ListBoxExtended : ListBox
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues
    {
        get
        {
            var results = new List<String>();
            if (SelectionMode == ListSelectionMode.Single)
            {
                results.Add(SelectedValue);
            }
            else
            {                    
                foreach (ListItem item in Items)                    
                    if (item.Selected)
                        results.Add(item.Value);                    
            }
            return results;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, you can use SelectedValues new property in a ControlParameter in your ObjectDatasource

Remember to register ListBoxExtended namespace and assembly in your .aspx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyExtendedControls" 
             Namespace="MyControls" TagPrefix="custom" %>
```

And replace `<aspnet:Listbox ...>` with:

```
<custom:ListBoxExtended  ... > ... </custom:ListBoxExtended>
```